# Trying to understand how to get NOMA data rates

Tags: noma

I am trying to understand the following example:

[image]

I understand all of them except the R2 for NOMA. What is the value of h2? and what is the value of N2? Also do we use the freq BW anywhere in these formulas?

Thanks

Comment: $h$ in communications engineering is most commonly a channel coefficient, as hinted at in the formulas next to the "lightning symbols".

Comment: @MarcusMüller so h is the freq bw so 1hz in this case? then what is N2?

Comment: no, it's not. It's the *channel coefficient*, not the bandwidth. If this tells you nothing, you will have to look it up – you really can't understand NOMA when you cannot even describe the literally simplest channel possible!

Comment: And I mean you literally have 3 variables in your rate equations, and you don't understand 2 of them. You **will** have to go back and do some basics.